# Starting reading from specific line numbers in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I have a file with 1000s of numbers like:

```
0000
0032
1201
:  :
:  :
:  :
2324
```

Depending on an input parameter "n", I want to read "m" numbers from this file from line numbers "n" to "n+m-1".

Any ideas how can I do this in Fortran?

Comment: Yeah, that looks fairly straightforward.  Post your code and we'll have a look at it, help you fix any problems you've got, maybe suggest style or performance improvements.

Comment: I don't have a code yet. I am stuck at this. I just need a basic code which can do what I mentioned above. Can you please provide me with basic solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't  know if you have tried it yourself, but here is an minimal example:
say, your input file looks like this:

```
0000
0032
1201
1234
4567
7890
2324
```

use this code (after reading it)

```
Program jhp
Implicit None
integer :: i
integer, parameter :: &
     m=7, &    !total number of line
     n=4, &    !line to skip
     p=3      !lines to read
integer,dimension(m)::arr   !file to read

open(12,file='file_so',status='old')
do i=1,n
  read(12,*)arr(i)
end do
do i=1,p
  read(12,*)arr(i)
  write(*,*)arr(i)
end do
End Program jhp
```

This skips first n line, and reads p lines after that.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

may be,

```
open (unit, file ...)
do i=1,n
 read(unit,*) crap
end do

do i =n,n+m-1
 read(unit,*) whatever
end do
close(unit)
```

is what you are looking for. this is untasted, but may give you a go.

edit: direct access is better for this type of job:
Just realised, though this is the easiest one, not the preferred one.
You can open the file in direct access mode and complete your job as:

```
OPEN( unit, file, ACCESS='DIRECT', RECL=100, FORM='FORMATTED')

READ( unit, *, REC=n, ERR=10 ) x
```

Comment: Just realised, though this is the easiest one, not the preferred one.
You can open the file in direct access mode and complete your job as:


 OPEN( unit, file, ACCESS='DIRECT', RECL=100, &   FORM='FORMATTED', ERR=90 )

 READ( 2, FMT='(I10,F10.3)', REC=13, ERR=30 ) A, B

Comment: @Rurda -- you can only use direct access if the numbers are really all exactly 4 digits and you set recl = 5 (add one for the CR).  You also can not use *, you need an explicit  format

Comment: @george, yes...sorry! I had just edited a sequential file open/read statement and missed that bit.